# Share the object on real-time, singeltond pattern

Tags: android

I simply have not found a solution to share a real-time data between the activitys. My first activity receives real-time object (type double, a random numbers). And i want to pas this numbers to second activity. It all works, only the second Activity shows only one time the data. I have to refresh the activity by going back to first activity and only then the second activity show the latest data. I implemented a Singelton pattern:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{
 public double xAxis;
 public double yAxis;
 public static FirstView instance;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.device_view);

        handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    int data1 = msg.arg1;
                    xAxis = (double) data1;
                    dataX.setText(String.valueOf(xAxis));
                    int data2 = msg.arg2;
                    yAxis = (double) data2;
                    dataY.setText(String.valueOf(yAxis));

                }
            };
        secondview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                }
            });

    }

     public static void initInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
    {
       instance = new FirstActivity();
    }
     }

    public static FirstActivity getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

SecondView class

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
       private double valueX;
    private double valueY;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linegraph); 
        valueX = FirstActivity.getInstance().xAxis;
        valueY = FirstActivity.getInstance().yAxis;
      }
}
```

Application class

```
package com.bluetoothcomm;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        initSingeltons();
    }

    public void initSingeltons(){
        FirstActivity.initInstance();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may implement a background service capable of providing the real time data to Activity1 and also to Activity2. I am guessing that your problem ocurrs if you are passing data from Activity1 to Activity2 through an Intent with putExtras, on this way it will only do this at the moment you start Activity2.

Comment: I have tryd the folowing: 1)Serializable putSerializable(VAR, current); 2)Intent with putExtra(), 3)Singleton and its always the same results. Whenever i switch to Second activity it shows only one time the data. Now i use Singelton and hte complete code with SIngeltond i added to my question @Max Rasguido

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem and the solution is to use `Application`. Only this dose not solves my problem. The problem is that the static variable instance `public static FirstView instance` is bound to the class loader, the first class that initilize that. So when the static variable inside any class has been initilized by an Activity and when the second Activity is started the first Activity is destroyed, so this means the static variable is also uninitilized. Thats why the SecondActivity dose not gets the up to date data or real time data, it catches only static constant data.

I changed my code a littele bit with the combination of Singelton and Application, couse this way the static variable should never be uninitilized when SecondActivity is activated. But i still get the same results, the static variable instance is uninitilized when i swtich to Second Activity. I am doing somethink wrong, does any one sees it. I added my code.

@Max Rasguido, @Orabig

Answer (score 0):

You should use the intent process. [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

How is your data supposed to change when activity2 is shown, if you say that it's received by activity1 ?

However, I would use a preference, or an attribute of your application class (which is a singleton itself), but you give too little informations to fully understand your needs...

Comment: i posted my Singelton implementation in my question @Orabig

Comment: I still don't get it. How is your data "received" (and from where) ? You don't show the code where xAxis and yAxis are updated. If it's inside the First Activity, then this code cannot work inside Activity 2.

Comment: i receive the data from inputstream from the other class. This other class it uses a handler to obtain and sendMessage to my view that call a FirstAcitvity and from the FirstActivity i want to share with SecondActivity by using a singelton. Indeed the xAxis and y are updated in the FirstActivity @Orabig

Comment: i added my question, indeed it was dificult to read, couse in reality i use other names for the classes. I cahnged the code on my question, this time is with Singleton and Application. @Orabig

Comment: Ok, I get it (even if I don't know where the inputstream comes from..). It is a very bad architectural practice anyway. You should absolutely avoid having a reference on any activity, as it is against the Android principles. As Max suggested, you should use a background service that will handle the input data. Any activity in your app will then be able to get the datas.

Comment: So you mean i have to use Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html ???
@Orabig

Comment: Maybe, but can you explain further the real source of the datas ? You mentioned an InputStream, but it's a little fuzzy....